# How to get OnClick on the icon/logo of an ActionBar

Tags: android

How can I get on click action, when I clicked actionbar logo. I tried

> onOptionsItemSelected
>
> case android.R.id.home://here to get action

and it does not work. I tried to add onClick listener on my decor view like this at onCreate

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnClickListener(this);
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(this);
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setOnClickListener(this);
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setOnTouchListener(this);
```

and I implemented simple listener

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "onTouch pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "onClick pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But it does not enter none of the methods. How can I get OnClick action on icon or onclick action when user clicked at Top Left corner of my decorview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the logo to be a clickable button:

```
myActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Then, override this method to get clicks:

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
```

Comment: cannot override the public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) it's declared as final in AppCompatActivity

Comment: Try overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` instead if you can't override `onMenuItemSelected`